# A property of a complex number equation

Tags: complex-numbers

> For all natural number $m>1$ and complex number $z$ with $|z|=1$. Prove that equation $$\left(\frac{1+ ix}{1 - ix}\right)^m = z$$ all solutions $x$ are real numbers.

Can i prove that the LHS is a real number, hence RHS is a real number? $z$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

If $|z|=1$ then  $\left|\frac{{1 + ix}}{{1 - ix}}\right|=|z|^{1/m}=1$. Hence, by letting $x=a+ib$ with $a=\mbox{Re}(x)$ and $b=\mbox{Im}(x)$, we get
$$(1-b)^2+a^2=|1 + ix|^2=|1 - ix|^2=(1+b)^2+(-a)^2\implies -2b=2b\implies b=0$$
which means that $x$ is a real number (its imaginary part is zero)